# Refocusing problem on TextField, cursor doesn't show on right position

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

When I unfocus on a TextField with existing Text then refocus on it again, the cursor always shows up at the start position, not at the tapped position. So I apply the logic of unfocusing from `flutter_keyboard_visibility` package - `KeyboardDismissOnTap Widget` and it still doesn't work. But when I wrapped my widget with this widget, it works the way I wanted to.

What's the difference if I wrap my widget with this KeyboardDismissOnTap Widget and when I use the same logic of that widget to my widget? I think It's basically the same, but it's not working the same way.

KeyboardDismissOnTap

```
class KeyboardDismissOnTap extends StatelessWidget {
  const KeyboardDismissOnTap({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  void _hideKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
    final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.hasFocus) {
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _hideKeyboard(context),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

MyPage - copied the logic of KeyboardDismissOnTap. Refocusing not working as intended, cursor still shows at start of existing text

```
class Mypage extends StatelessWidget {

  const Mypage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void _hideKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
    final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.hasFocus) {
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _hideKeyboard(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController()..text = 'Existing Text Here',
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                  //Unfocus function here
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Unfocus'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

MyPage - wrapped with KeyboardDismissOnTap. Refocusing works correctly, cursor shows at the right position where you tapped it.

```
class Mypage extends StatelessWidget {

  const Mypage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardDismissOnTap(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController()..text = 'Existing Text Here',
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (!FocusScope.of(context).hasPrimaryFocus && FocusScope.of(context).hasFocus) {
                      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Unfocus'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```